# Adding Spark Partition as a column without reading all files

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

Using spark 2.1.
What is the best way to ensure that the partition column used when writing a dataframe out to parquet gets added back into a dataframe after reading it back in without using `/*` across all of the files? Just want to `s3a://my/path/part={2018-*}` and make sure that the `part` column I originally used becomes available when I read it.

I thought that `basePath` option takes care of this where it just adds any of the partitions following the path as a column but can't seem to get it to work.

Tried this out: 
my files are pretty standard and look like this and I want `part` added back in as a column:

```
s3a://my/path/part=20170101
s3a://my/path/part=20170102
```

This is not working:

```
spark.read
  .option("BasePath", "s3a://my/path/")
  .parquet(filePath)
```

Am I just thinking about this incorrectly and I should be reading all of the files and then filtering after? I thought a main benefit of partitioning by a column is that you can then just be able to read a subset of the files by using the partition.

Comment: What you're looking for is partition pruning. Which I'm sure S3 parquet  files support, since S3 has no concept of folders. Therefore, you're not reading a column, you're reading a file prefix

Comment: `.option("BasePath", "s3a://my/path/")` because option name is `basePath` not `BasePath`

Comment: Don't mention it :) If think we close it as a _simple typographical error_ :)